# How to add react-native-cookies to new version of react-native?

Tags: java, android, react-native

How to add react native cookies to MainApplication.java? - [Github Repo: react-native-cookies](https://github.com/joeferraro/react-native-cookies)

```
@Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
      List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
      // Packages that cannot be autolinked yet can be added manually here, for example:
       //packages.add(new MainReactPackage());
        // return Arrays.asList(
        //     new MainReactPackage(),
        //     new CookieManagerPackage()
        // );

       //I'm try this, but not working... generate a error on build...
        packages.add(new MainReactPackage());
        packages.add(new CookieManagerPackage());


      return packages;
    }
```

Has show this:

[image]

Comment: Please don't use images to include text error messages. Copy the text of the error message and add it to the question and then format it appropriately. Images of text are not accessible, nor are they searchable.

Comment: In this case the image is not even readable...

Comment: [Stack Overflow Discourages screenshots of code, errors & data](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors).  It is likely, the question will be downvoted, for containing unnecessary screenshots.  By using screenshots, you are discouraging anyone from assisting you.  No one wants to retype your stuff, from a screenshot, and screenshots are often, not readable.

Comment: The image is for illustration only, it is not the root of the problem.